# Getting on 500 Internal Server Error On PHP saving Canvas as Image

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, html5-video

Trying to save Raphael Paper on Server as an Image I have following code:

```
$(function() {

$("#printBtn").click(function() {

var svg1 = $("#map > svg").get();
var svg = $('#map').html().replace(/>\s+/g, ">").replace(/\s+</g, "<").replace(/<canvas.+/g,"");
// strips off all spaces between tags

canvg('cvs', svg, {        
ignoreMouse: true, 
ignoreAnimation: true
});  
var canvas  = document.getElementById('cvs');
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
});          
});     

});
</script>
```

and on my process.php I have :

```
<?php
$data = substr($_POST['imageData'], strpos($_POST['imageData'], ",") + 1);
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
fclose();
echo "/canvas.png";
```

but I am getting 500 Internal Server Error from process.php

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how can I stop it?

Thanks

Comment: You should roll-back your edit as your question description and my answer now don't make any sense any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is coming from the server, not from javascript which runs in the browser. So the problem is in your php script.

There you have a simple syntax error:

```
data = substr($_POST['imageData'], strpos($_POST['imageData'], ",") + 1);
```

Should be:

```
$data = substr($_POST['imageData'], strpos($_POST['imageData'], ",") + 1);
^ here
```

By the way, when you get 500 errors, you should always check the server error log and / or display errors in php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Possibly combined with something like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jeroen, can you please also let me know how I can save the image in specific folder?

Comment: The reason that I am asking this is after correcting the mistake on the code I am getting  Not Found , The requested URL /canvas.png was not found on this server. on responde.

Comment: @Suffii That seems a bit out of scope, but can't you just add the path before the filename? I don't understand what the problem is exactly.

Comment: @Suffii Where is it then? Putting it in a sub-folder of something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` would seem like a good idea to not fill up your web-root with images.